# How to quickly fill NaN values in a row with the ones in a list of similar rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a large Dataframe (about 800,000 rows). Nearly 30% of the rows have NaN values, for example,

```
test = pd.DataFrame({"name": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 
                     "col1": ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5', 'c6', 'c7'], 
                     "col2": [4, 5, 6, np.nan, np.nan, 8, 5], 
                     "col3": [7, 8, 9, np.nan, np.nan, 3, 7], 
                     "col4": [7, 8, 9, np.nan, np.nan, 2, 6]})
```

```
    name  col1  col2   col3  col4    
0    1     c1    4.0    7.0   7.0
1    2     c2    5.0    8.0   8.0    
2    3     c3    6.0    9.0   9.0    
3    4     c4    NaN    NaN   NaN    
4    5     c5    NaN    NaN   NaN    
5    6     c6    8.0    3.0   2.0    
6    7     c7    5.0    7.0   6.0
```

Now I have NaN in row3 and row4.

And based on some rules, I get the most similar rows for row3 are

```
similar_for_row3 = ['name' = 10, 'name' = 3, 'name' = 1]
```

and for row4 are

```
similar_for_row4 = ['name' = 2, 'name' = 6, 'name' = 20].
```

Then, my questions are:

1. how can I quickly check if these rows in `similar_for_row3` and `similar_for_row4` are in the Dataframe, e.g., `'name' = 10` and `'name' = 20` are not in it.
2. quickly replace the `NaN` values in a row with the ones in similar rows. For example, for `row3`, we first check all the rows in `similar_for_row3`, then use the first row that existed in the Dataframe (which is `test.loc[test['name' == 3]]`) to replace the `NaN` in `row3`.

The output is:

```
    name  col1  col2   col3  col4    
0    1     c1    4.0    7.0   7.0    
1    2     c2    5.0    8.0   8.0    
2    3     c3    6.0    9.0   9.0    
3    4     c4    6.0    9.0   9.0  -> replace NaN with 'name' = 3    
4    5     c5    NaN    NaN   NaN    
5    6     c6    8.0    3.0   2.0    
6    7     c7    5.0    7.0   6.0
```

I tried to iterate all the Dataframe with "for loop" to replace the NaN values, but it's very slow. It costs my about 3 seconds to replace one row. And my data set has 800,000 rows. It will cost my a month to do it. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. How can I quickly check if these rows in similar_for_row3 and similar_for_row4 are in the Dataframe, e.g., 'name' = 10 and 'name' = 20 are not in it.

You can find the intersection of the two `sets` using `&`, and use `sorted` setting `key= similar_for_row3.index` so that the first intersection that appears in `similar_for_row3` is used:

```
similar_for_row4 = [2, 6, 20]
fill_with  = sorted(list(set(similar_for_row4) & set(test.name.values)), 
       key= similar_for_row4.index)[0]
#2
```

So here row 2 will be used to replace row 4, as it is as you mention "the first row that existed in the Dataframe".

> 2. Quickly replace the NaN values in a row with the ones in similar rows. For example, for row3, we first check all the rows in similar_for_row3, then use the first row that existed in the Dataframe (which is test.loc[test['name' == 3]]) to replace the NaN in row3.

You could first create a mask using `.isnull()` on the dataframe sliced on the specific row, and perform boolean indexation on the dataframe to filter the corresponsing columns with the ones of, in this case, row 2:

```
row = 4
mask = test.loc[row, :].isnull().squeeze()
test.loc[row, mask] = test.loc[fill_with, mask].values
```

So for this example, you would have:

```
    name col1 col2  col3  col4
0     1   c1   4.0   7.0   7.0
1     2   c2   5.0   8.0   8.0
2     3   c3   6.0   9.0   9.0
3     4   c4   NaN   NaN   NaN
4     5   c5   6.0   9.0   9.0
5     6   c6   8.0   3.0   2.0
6     7   c7   5.0   7.0   6.0
```

**Update**

In order to easily detect the rows where any NaNs are present you can do:

```
has_nans = test[test.isnull().any(axis=1)].index.values
```

And the simply loop over `has_nans` finding the most similar row with which to replace in each iteration.

Comment: Hi Nixon, you solution is very helpful. I have one more question- do I have to loop all the rows that have NaN values and repeat the solution you gave, or do you know a better way to do it?

Comment: Glad it helped. Updated with some tips on this. Please don't forget to accept if it helped